# Set Input Value for Google autocomplete textbox

Tags: php, session, autocomplete, setvalue

I have a form which allow users to enter addresses (google places autocomplete). when that form is submitted, the value is stored as a `$_SESSION` variable and post. Now when the user clicks back, I want to set the value of the address input box with the `$_SESSION` variable but I can't seem to get it working.

```
<input class="form-control" name ="collectPoint"  required="true"  type="text" id="search-field-from" <?      
       if(isset($_SESSION['collectPoint'])){echo 'value =$_SESSION['collectPoint']';}
             else{ echo 'placeholder="Collection Location"';} ?> >
```

Comment: <input class="form-control" name ="collectPoint"  required="true"  type="text" id="search-field-from" <? if(isset($_SESSION['collectPoint'])){echo 'value =$_SESSION['collectPoint']';}else{ echo 'placeholder="Collection Location"';} ?> >
          </div>

Comment: add this code to question;

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['collectPoint']))
{
    $collectPoint = "value='".$_SESSION['collectPoint']."'";
}
else
{ 
    $collectPoint = "placeholder='Collection Location'";
} ?>    


<input class="form-control" name ="collectPoint" required="true" type="text" id="search-field-from" <?php echo $collectPoint; ?>/>
```

Comment: Thanks but I think the issue is with Google place autocomplete. When I set a value (e.g. Value ="test address">). When the page loads, it appears then disappears again. any ideas?